# Uint8 is not convertible to Int ( saving a game best time )

Tags: ios, swift

Basically, I am using

`var highscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()`

to save the high score, which in this case is a time.  The problem I am having is that the stopwatch timer is using Uint8 and I get the error "Uint8 is not convertible to Int"

This is driving me a bit nuts trying to fix this and I am concluding the simplest way is to convert the Uint8 values into Int, so that the fastest time can be saved in the game as a high score.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

The 'startSeconds' and 'startFraction' variables are in Uint8 .. but the 'hseconds' and 'hfrac' variables need to be Int in order to be saved.

The error is happening on these lines:

```
hseconds = startSeconds
hfrac = startFraction
```

Here the relevant function:

```
func stop() {


    hseconds = startSeconds
    hfrac = startFraction

    if (hseconds < highscoreSec) {


        // && (fraction < highscoreFrac)

        //highscoreSec = startSeconds
        //highscoreFrac = startFraction


        highscoreDefault.setValue(highscoreSec, forKey: "seconds")
        highscoreDefault.setValue(highscoreFrac, forKey: "frac")
    }

    highscoreDefault.synchronize()

    timer.invalidate()
    timer == 0
}
```

here is more code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var highscoreDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    playButton.hidden = true

    if (highscoreDefault.objectForKey("seconds") != nil) { highscoreSec = highscoreDefault.valueForKey("seconds")as NSInteger!
    }

    if (highscoreDefault.objectForKey("frac") != nil) { highscoreFrac = highscoreDefault.valueForKey("frac")as NSInteger!
    }

    highscoreLabel.text = "(highscoreSec):\(highscoreFrac)"

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

If you noticed, some of the lines are commented out as part of the debugging process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried this?

```
let hseconds = Int(startSeconds) 
let hfrac = Int(startFraction)
```

EDIT: variable names

Comment: I changed your code to say "Int" instead of "int" and no errors.. I will compile now

Comment: Oh yes, sorry forgot about the swift syntax

Comment: That apparently fixed the bug, but I am still having an issue with it thinking the high score is 0, so I am troubleshooting that at the moment.  I will award you with the correct answer after I figure this out.  Thanks so much for your quick help.

Comment: If you have any more troubles, and need help, feel free to ask! Glad I could help.

Comment: i am posting another question now.  Apparently, it is not giving me the value I need.

Comment: let startSeconds  = seconds > 9 ? String(seconds):"0" + String(seconds)
        let startFraction = fraction > 9 ? String(fraction):"0" + String(fraction)
        
        displayTimeLabel.text = "\(startSeconds):\(startFraction)"
        var penalty = String(format: "%0.2f", arguments:[timepenalty])
        penaltylabel.text = "+ " + penalty
        let hseconds = Int(startSeconds)
        let hfrac = Int(startFraction)
        
        
    }

Comment: i have to wait 90 minutes before it allows me to post another question, but basically in the above code it gives me an error "Cannot invoke init with argument type string' , for the last 2 lines :

Comment: error is on let hfrac = Int(startFraction) and let seconds = Int(startSeconds)

Comment: it was giving 0 as the fastest time because it is not pulling the value correctly from the stopwatch function

Comment: Actually the data I need is within a local variable in a different function.  Is there a way to define a global variable with a value from a local variable?

Comment: Save it to a global variable.

Comment: how to save it to a global variable?  Do I have to rewrite the whole stopwatch function to use global variables?  Thanks

Comment: I assume you have the stopwatch function in the model part of the project. So simply save it to a global var in the stopwatch function, then write a method that returns that global variable if it's not nil. Simply call the method there, where you need the data.

Answer (score 1):

This works like a charm:

```
let a : UInt8 = 20
var b : Int = 0
b = Int(a)
println(b)
// Prints "20"
```